# How do I search for a word/phrase between page x and page y of a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, search, find, pdf-reader

While working with a 700+ page PDF for school, I need to search for words/phrases in the current chapter we're in but most "Find" features on PDF viewers will give me results from all over the PDF. Does anyone know of a way or a program that will let you search between 2 pages? (So if Chapter 4 is page 100 to 150 I can use the search feature to search between those two pages only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use your PDF-Printer and print the pages of your chapter. Then open this *new* PDF and search.